# Send NSString variable to WCF service

Tags: ios, objective-c, wcf

I have encountered an issue with my code, when I want to send an `NSString` variable to my WCF web service.

Code:

```
NSString *str= @"http://IPdAddress/myService.svc/json/";
str=[str stringByAppendingFormat:@"InsertNewWeight/%@",noteWeight.text];

NSURL *WcfSeviceURL = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:WcfSeviceURL];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

This code is working fine if I enter the `noteWeight.text` value as a simple word.

When I entered the `noteWeight.text` value as a complex word (two words separated by a space) the system returns an error `data parameter is nil`

Can anybody help me please on this? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried encoding str? str=[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
                        NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: but when I send a date with a **[formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:MM:SS"]** the data cannot inserted in my database, and when I replace the ':' by '-' the data then inserted ? can you clarify please ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is passed in the URL and not as a POST argument, you should URL-encode your `noteWeight.text` string, like this:

```
str = [str stringByAppendingFormat:@"InsertNewWeight/%@", [noteWeight.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

The spaces will be sent as `%20`, and other special characters will also be encoded to be correctly read on the server-side.

Comment: can you clarify that please :  when I sent a date with a [formatter setDateFormat:@"HH:MM:SS"] the data cannot inserted in my database, and when I replace the ':' by '-' the data then inserted ?

Comment: It is probably related to how the database engine on server side accepts date literals. But it is another topic, please create another question because it is not related to this one.

Comment: thanks, just to let you know that my Database accept the ':', when I replace the '-' by ':' in server side the data inserted correctly !.